# What do maximal subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are closed under addition and multiplication and don't contain additive inverses look like?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have a subset $A \subset\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following conditions:

- $\forall x,y \in A: \{x+y,xy\} \subset A$
- $A \cup (-A) = \mathbb{R}$
- $A \cap (-A) = \{0\}$

We know that $ A = [0,\infty)$ satisfies these conditions, but is this the only set with these properties?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $x\geq0$ then either $\sqrt x$ or $-\sqrt x$ is in $A$, and so is its square.

Comment: Why does that matter though? How can I explicitly disprove that there is no subset $A$ that contains numbers like $e$ or $\pi$?

Comment: @Nicholas, let $r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and suppose that $-r\in A$. As $A\cup(-A)=\mathbb{R}$ we have that $\sqrt{r}\in A$ or $-\sqrt{r}\in A$, then $(\pm\sqrt{r})^{2}=r\in A$ which is a contradiction.